# Is there a purpose to all the testing in Portal?

Tags: portal-series

There are billions of dollars thrown at the wall to see what sticks in the test chambers of the Portal Franchise. Lots of testers, thousands of cubes, a sadistic robot, all of it to be used in the testing chambers.

I understand that some testing is required to test certain devices (Long Fall Boots,  Gels, etc) , but GladOS STOCKPILED chambers. Is there something throughout the series that explains this?

Comment: "...we do what we must, because we can..."

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: This question isn't very useful to users who may come, and IMO should probably be closed. It also shows little research effort, but also touches on dev-only knowledge, which is off-topic.

Comment: Dev Only knowlege? I am sorry, but it regards story knowlege

Answer (score 9):

GladOS explains in Portal 2 that testing gives the AI an euphoric feeling. So at least the robots do testing as an end to its own. The humans were actually trying to do science and develop products (or something...)

Comment: They had just as much test chambers then. I wouldn't call this a full answer.

Comment: more chambers = more data-points

Comment: @user2977079 GlaDOS *always* got this euphoric feeling, even though it is only explained in the second game. The only thing that kept her from going into a complete meltdown was the fact that she kept testing.